# Google Services dependencies conflicts

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to update each lib in my project. Right now my grade looks like this :

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1'
```

And I'm getting error :

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1
```

When you check you can see that latest version of analytics service is 16.0.1. So I change grade like this :

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1"
    **compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1"**
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    **compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'**
```

I'm getting error :

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.1.
```

Maybe you know how can I fix this ?

Comment: Why did you down vote my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `google services` lib too. Go to your main `App's gradle` file and make sure it looks something like this:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @Bartos Glad it help. happy coding :)

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning; versioning of libraries is now mostly independent of one another after version 15.0.0.

Comment: @zfromg i know that OP's problem was in project build.gradle file now with the dependencies.